# Junit5 Tag Annotation together with Quarkus QuarkusTestResource Annotation

Tags: java, integration-testing, junit5, quarkus, maven-surefire-plugin

How can QuarkusTestResource be used in conjunction with Tag Annotation?

Example Test Routine

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import io.quarkus.test.common.QuarkusTestResource;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;

@QuarkusTest
@Tag("integration")
@QuarkusTestResource(DatabaseResource.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void () {
        doTests...
    }

}
```

Maven Snippet:

```xml
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.12.1.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.12.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</surefire-plugin.version>
    <testscope>unit</testscope>
...
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <groups>${testscope}</groups>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
...
```

Maven Command:

```
./mvnw clean test
```

Result: QuarkusTestResource are started even if no QuarkusTest is annotated with "unit", so it seems that Quarkus is not aware of the Tag Annotation?

Answer (score 1):

Quarkus Test Resources are global which means it will run anyway, even if your class is annotated with a tag that shouldn't run.

To prevent this, try annotating your class with

```
@QuarkusTestResource(restrictToAnnotatedClass = true)
```

From the [Quarkus' website](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing)

> test resources are global, even if they are defined on a test class or custom profile, which means they will all be activated for all tests, even though we do remove duplicates. **If you want to only enable a test resource on a single test class or test profile, you can use @QuarkusTestResource(restrictToAnnotatedClass = true).**

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is likely the `tags` methof of `QuarkusTestProfile`. See [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#running-specific-tests) part of the documentation